# C# - If instance creation of member is not allowed in static class - Is the following declaration valid ?(Code is working)

Tags: c#, .net

```
public static class MyClass

  {

    // why it is allowed ?

    public static Random r = new Random();

    // We receive error can not declare instance members in a static class

    public static int someVal=new int();


  }
```

Why is it allowed in C# to have the following declaration valid in static class context ?

**public static Random r = new Random();**

**Update :**

The code is working properly.So no issues.Thanks for your support.

Comment: Your class compiles fine. Both the static int and static Random is allowed.

Comment: Please post the correct code.

Comment: Yes the mistake is mine.It is compiled .sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is, your code compiles just fine.
You'll only receive the error you described if you delete the static from

```
public static int someVal=new int();
```

such as in

```
public int someVal=new int();
```

That happens because all members of a static class have to be static too.

Answer (score 2):

The premise in the question(-title) is wrong, the creation of an instance for a static member is *not* invalid.

Comment: :) I am unable to delete my silly question.can anybody delete it?